# Selenium IDE - variable unusuable in "execute script" due to apostrophe in the string

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I use the Selenium IDE browser extension. It stores the text value of an HTML element in a variable using "store". Unfortunately the value of this HTML element has an apostrophe `'`. As a result, when I call "execute script" to process the string, such as "return ${a}.length", this fails. This is because ${a} is substituted for its value like the C preprocessor -- literally being substituted instead of copying its value. Inexplicably, in JS `"'".length == 1` works correctly, while "return ${a}.length" does not. Neither does "return "${a}".length" or "return '${a}'.length" or "return '${${a}}'.length".

How do I correctly use the value of a `store`d variable containing an `'` from the JS in `execute script` correctly?

Relevant: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium-ide/issues/543

Answer (score 0):

I worked around it by using "execute script" to find that element and replace apostrophe with something else before storing the element value